# loading images from documents directory into an array

Tags: nsmutablearray, coverflow, nsdocumentdirectory

I have some jpg images I am saving to the documents directory from camera shots.  I want to find all the jpg images in the documents directory and load them into an array so they can be in a overflow view.

Here is my code to find and sort the jpg images in the documents directory.

```
   NSString *extension = @"jpg";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];



        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];  
        NSMutableArray *jpegFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [contents count]];

       NSString *filename;
        for (filename in contents)

        {
            if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) 
                     {
             [jpegFiles addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]]];


            }
        }

    // Add the coverflow view
    coverflow = [[TKCoverflowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    coverflow.coverflowDelegate = self;
    coverflow.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:coverflow];
    [coverflow setNumberOfCovers:6];

- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasBroughtToFront:(int)index{
        NSLog(@"Front %d",index);
}

- (TKCoverflowCoverView*) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndex:(int)index{


    TKCoverflowCoverView *cover = [coverflowView dequeueReusableCoverView];

    if(cover == nil){
        // Change the covers size here
        cover = [[TKCoverflowCoverView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 210)]; // 224
        cover.baseline = 200;

    }
    cover.image = [covers objectAtIndex:index % [covers count]];

    return cover;

}
```

I have tried everything I can think of and nothing works.

It has been suggested that I load each image by getting the path to the image from the array of pathnames, and use the method imageWithContentsOfFile to load the image.

I have looked this up and did searches for how to do this but with no luck.  Could someone show me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it as below,

```
if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) 
{
     [jpegFiles addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]]];
}
```

Comment: The code is fine through                                              {if([[filename pathExtension]isEqualToString:extension])

Comment: sorry took to long on other edit here The code is fine through                                              {if([[filename pathExtension]isEqualToString:extension])              {[jpegFiles addObject: filename];}}  It creates an array with the file names for all the image files with the .jpg extension.  I tried to use your code but it didn't work. What I want to do is just load the files in the jpegFiles array into the covers array and use them but don't really know how have tried arrayWithArray, arrayWithArray  Copy just keeps on crashing.  I really appreciate your help and input.

Comment: The code I gave, gives you UIImage objects of all the jpeg files from your documentsDirectory in the jpegFiles array.

Comment: So I have revised my code to reflect what you suggested, along with the code for the rest of the page that is relevant.  When I run the program it crashes saying the **'***-[NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] object cannot be nil'** maybe I'm doing something wrong. can you point out my mistake?

Comment: Oops. A small correction! Instead of [UIImage imageNamed:path]; Use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, I should type in

Comment: SUPER that did it you are great.  One more question if I could and if not I will post a new question.  If you look at the middle of my original post there is a line    '[coverflow setNumberOfCovers:6];'  How can I make the number 6 a variable that reflex the # of images in jpegFiles?

Comment: [coverflow setNumberOfCovers:[jpegFiles count]];

Comment: Thanks, I thought that's what I should do so did it before I read your post. I guess I must be learning something.  Thank you for the reply.